How to replace actual Image with dummy image when image is not present
<div className="bg-[#F8F8F8] flex items-center justify-center px-2 py-10">
  <Image src={image} alt="course image" width={100} height={100} />
</div>

When the image is unavailable due to an error, I want to replace it with a dummy image. How can I do that?

import fallbackImage from ./assets/dummy-image.jpg;
import the fallback image and Conditional src:
The src attribute uses the original image. If the original image is unavailable or fails to load, the src event handler sets the src to the fallback image.
src={image || fallbackImage}


To replace a failing image with a dummy image in a React component, you can use the onError event on the Image tag to handle image loading errors. Here's a simplified version:
import Image from 'next/image';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function CourseImage({ src }) {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(src);

  const handleError = () => {
    setImageUrl('/path-to-your-dummy-image.png'); // Replace with your dummy image path
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-[#F8F8F8] flex items-center justify-center px-2 py-10">
      <Image
        src={imageUrl}
        alt="course image"
        width={100}
        height={100}
        onError={handleError}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CourseImage;

Key Points:

Use useState to manage the image URL.
Use the onError callback to switch to a dummy image if the original fails to load.

